# Unable to select table in mysql

Tags: mysql

This is mysql table:

```
+---------------------+

| Tables_in_myproject |

+---------------------+

| reds                |

| zxy                 |

| abcd                |

| release             |

+---------------------+
```

4 rows in set (0.46 sec)

When I try to select or show release table it throws the following error:

```
mysql> select * from release;

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'release' at line 1
```

What am I doing wrong? I am able to select all the other tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`release` is a [reserved keyword in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) and needs to be escaped by backticks.

```
select * from `release`;
```

Comment: I tried that too, i get the same error.
select * from 'release';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''release'' at line 1

Comment: I would strongly recommend that you don't name your table and columns using reserved words. Backticks are not the same as single-quotes.

Comment: You used quotes. Backticks are something else. use quotes for strings and backticks for column and table names.

Answer (score 0):

`release` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html). use backticks arround or better change the table name.

```
select * from `release`;
```